# What is the difference between number command motion and command number motion

Tags: vim

I'm learning vim with vimtutor. I was wondering if there is a difference between command motion number and number command motion. 
For example:
`2dw` seems to me to work exactly like `d2w`, similarly `2dd` does the same as `d2d`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two numbers are both called `[count]`, in your example, indeed, they do same job. But the two counts come from different concept.

```
[count]command
```

this will do the command `[count]` times, `2dd` does `dd` twice; `2dw` does `dw` twice.

The second is from the `{motion}`, `2w`, `2j` etc.

If you want to see some differences, here are two I can think of:

- Some commands don't support `{motion}`. For example, the `X`, you press `2X`, will remove 2 characters before the cursor. However, you cannot do `X{motion}`. other commands that don't support `{motion}` `p (paste)`, `s` etc. You can do `2p`, `2s`, but you cannot do `p2w` `s3w`

You get same result from `2dw` and `d2w`, but the two `2` have different meaning, understanding what the number does is ok. you can combine the count and motion, like `2d3w`.

Comment: In your first bulleted difference, I believe your information is incorrect. I double-checked to make sure, but it looks like the repeat command will work with both 2dw and d2w and maintain the fact that they delete two words. I'm not sure if this was a recent change or not, but as of now, they both work with repeat.

Comment: @HoldenLewis yes, you are right, I just tested with my vim (latest version), it does what you have said. I don't remember when I posted the answer, it was wrongly tested or the `.` (repeat) behaved really differently in the old version. I just mark the 1st bullet as "deleted"

Comment: Kent, does it all mean that it's better to have a count in the very beginning, like `2dw` and `3de`, because it will work for _any_ commands, whereas things like `d2w` works for only some of them?

Comment: @jsv I won't say it is better or worse.  It depends on which way you get used to doing. But understand the meaning of the command is anyway important.

Answer (score 6):

The number command motion can use on all command, but number motion only in a few.

The most important is that repeat-action(.) redo the previous action.

Example:

`2dd`->`.` = `2dd`->`dd`

`d2d`->`.` = `d2d`->`d2d`

Usually, I suggest use the first command. Because it is easier to be repeated.

Comment: For those using the latest version of Vim this feature no longer holds true. In fact, I arrived at the same answer using both these repeat-action approaches.